# Modify in-place an array received as function argument

Tags: solidity, arrays, function-pointer

I have a function that performs some operations on an array:

`function foo(uint256[] myArray) public`

I would like this function to apply operations on `myArray` in-place. I tried to specify `storage` in the argument declaration but the compiler requires it to be declared as `memory` or `calldata`.

Is it possible to modify in-place an array fed to a function?

Comment: Could you be more specific on what you mean by "in place". Some example will help understand on what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: What I mean by in place is having a function that takes as an argument an array in storage and modifies it directly in storage without ever copying to memory.

Answer (score 2):

You can only use `storage` for function arguments if the function is not `public` or `external`.

Thus, changing your function visibility to `internal` or `private` should work:

```
function foo(uint256[] storage myArray) internal
```